# agregar items en array temporal o en localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estimados su apoyo por favor ya lo intente, de varias formas, necesito lograr lo siguiente tengo un listado de productos el cual se le a añadido un botón agregar, lo que se me pide es que al darle clic al botón agregar se pueda ir añadiendo los productos seleccionados en un array temporal o en el loclastorage, visualmente solo se debe mostrar el titulo del producto que se añadió, tengo la carga de los productos, pero no he podido lograr hacer el añadido y almacenarlo temporalmente.
esta echo en Angular. dejo una imagen de referencial y el código que tengo hasta el momento muchas Gracias.

la idea es hacer una especie de multiselect, pero en vez de que sea un dropdown donde seleccionas sea la lista de items que vayas haciendo clic y se vaya añadiendo el titulo
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { Coupon } from "../../../../business/savings-wallet/views/home/home.model";
import { CouponService } from "../../../../business/savings-wallet/services/couponService";
import {
  CouponUSer,
  CouponUSerDet,
} from "../../../../business/savings-wallet/models/registration-user.model";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import * as moment from "moment";
moment.locale("es");

@Component({
  selector: "fp-modal-coupons",
  templateUrl: "./modal-coupons.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./modal-coupons.component.scss"],
})
export class ModalCouponsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() coupons: Coupon[] = [];
  coupon: Coupon;
 
  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalCouponsComponent>,
    private couponService: CouponService
  ) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCoupons();
  }


  loadCoupons() {
    this.couponService
      .getApiKey(firebase.auth().app.options)
      .subscribe((key) => {
        const request = new CouponUSer({
          identificationDocument: sessionStorage.getItem("document"),
          limitAvailableStatus: 40,
          companyCode: "MF",
        });
        this.couponService
          .getCoupons(request, key.access_token)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            if (response.error !== null) {
            } else {
              this.coupons = response.data;
              this.loading = false;
              console.log(response.data);
            }
          });
      });
  }
  
  // intento algo como enviar el id o Barcode pero me trae siempre 1 elemento al invocar a otro item lo sobrescribe la idea es que se vallan sumando o añadiendo de uno en uno. creo que que algo me falta estoy haciendo un for pero no funciona, no se si estoy en lo correcto.
  agregar() {
    console.log('Ageegando!!!')
     this.couponService
   .getApiKey(firebase.auth().app.options)
   .subscribe((key) => {
     const requestDet = new CouponUSerDet({
       identificationDocument: sessionStorage.getItem("document"),
       id: coupon.barCode,
       couponTypeCode: 1,
       parentCampaignCode: "",
       idTracking: null,
       companyCode: "MF",
     });
     this.couponService
       .getCouponById(requestDet, key.access_token)
       .subscribe((response) => {
         this.coupon = response.data as Coupon;
         const datos = response.data;
         for (const id in datos) {
          console.log(`${id}: ${datos[id]}`);
        }
         //console.log(response.data, "ID2");
       });
   });
    }
   }
```

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Cupones y Código de Descuento</h2>
<div class="labels_add" *ngIf="coupon">
  <div>
    <span class="label">{{item.productName}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />

<mat-dialog-content>
  <div class="loader" *ngIf="loading"></div>
  <div *ngIf="coupons.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let coupon of coupons; let i = index">
      <div
        class="dialog-content"
        *ngIf="coupon.couponStatus === 2 ? false : true"
      >
        <div class="img-product">
          <img [src]="coupon.pathImage.small" [alt]="coupon.productName" />
        </div>
        <div class="description_product">
          <div class="title_product">{{ coupon.productName }}</div>
          <p class="texto_product">
            Válido del {{coupon.couponValidity.startDate | momentPipe:'D MMMM'}} al {{coupon.couponValidity.endDate | momentPipe:'D MMMM YYYY'}}.
            <span class="detail_product_mobile"
              ><button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialogDetail()">
                Ver más detalles
              </button></span
            >
          </p>
          <div class="detail_product_desktop">
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialogDetail()">
              Ver más detalles
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="add_button_mobile">
            <button (click)="agregar()">+ Agregar cupón</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add_button_desktop">
          <button (click)="agregar()">+ Agregar cupón</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

```js
tengo este codigo funciona cambia la clase como la nesecito, pero lo hace todo junto a todos los botones nesecito que sea de uno en uno como le voy dando click...

var elemento = document.querySelectorAll(".add_button_desktop");
    for (var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
    elemento[i].classList.add("disabled");
```

Comment: Hola alguien que de una mano, tal vez necesitan mas información tengo los .json de servicio, etc, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Segun entiendo lo que quieres es un tipo de "carrito" para agregar.
Se me ocurren 2 cosas:

la primera y mas Obvia, crear un array de constante que almacene y que el boton agregar haga push a ese array y alli se van almacenando. Se perderan si se refresca la app eso si.

La segunda no tan Obvia es meter un array al localStorage creando tres metodos: uno para reescribir el array dentro del localstorage, otro para leer ese array del localstorage y otro para guardar en el localstorage.

Recibe un array de cupones, los transforma en string y los guarda en el localStorage:

```
 saveStoreCupons(cupons: any[]){
   localStorage.setItem('arrayCupons', String(cupons))
 }
```

Guarda un cupon en el array de cupones del localStorage:

```
saveOneCupon(oneCupon: any){
  const arrayCupons: any[] = this.getStoreCupons();
  arrayCupons.push(oneCupon);
  this.saveStoreCupons(arrayCupons)
}
```

Extrae el array de cupones del localstorage, crea un nuevo array de cupones y lo retorna:

```
getStoreCupons(): any[] {
const arrayStorage: string =  localStorage.getItem('arrayCupons');
const newArraCupons: any[] = [];

if(arrayStorage !== ''){

  const arrayCupons: string[] = arrayStorage.split(',')

  arrayCupons.map((cupon: string, i:number) => {
    if( i + 1 === arrayCupons.length){
      let newCupon = JSON.parse(cupon);
      newArraCupons.push(newCupon);

    } else {
      let newCupon = JSON.parse(cupon);
      newArraCupons.push(newCupon);
    }
  })

  return newArraCupons

 } else {
  return []
  }
}
```

Espero sea util y te ayude de alguna manera.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un ejemplo simplificado. Un punto clave para lograr el objetivo está en la llamada a la función `agregar` la cual recibe un objeto de tipo producto y lo agrega al arreglo.

Cualquier duda puedes dejarla en los comentarios.

.html

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <span *ngFor="let p of productosSeleccionados" style="margin-left: 10px">{{p.nombre}}
</span>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let p of productos" style="margin: 15px">
  {{ p.nombre }} <button (click)="agregar(p)">Seleccionar</button>
</div>
```

.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  productosSeleccionados = []

  productos = [
    {
      id: 1, 
      nombre: 'producto 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2, 
      nombre: 'producto 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3, 
      nombre: 'producto 3'
    },
  ]

  agregar(producto: unknown){
    this.productosSeleccionados.push(producto)
  }

  
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gigc9p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

** Actualización **

Para prevenir duplicados se puede validar si el elemento ya está dentro del arreglo:

```
agregar(producto: any) {

    // si ya existe no hacer nada
    if (this.productosSeleccionados.some((p) => p === producto)) return;

    this.productosSeleccionados.push(producto);
  }
```

** Actualización **

Para marcar el botón del elemento que ya se agregó se puede agregar una función que busque en el arreglo de elementos seleccionados y si lo encuentra entonces se asigna una clase al botón:

.ts

```
isSelected(producto: any) {
    return this.productosSeleccionados.indexOf(producto) != -1;
  }
```

.html

```
<button
    (click)="agregar(p)"
    [ngClass]="{'selected' : isSelected(p)}"
  >...
```

.css

```
.selected{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: ya casi sale solo que ni bien me carga la pagina se ejecuta el for y se muestran los items, también lo hace al click como tu ejemplo, como evito que se ejecute el for al cargar la pagina, solo que se muestren al hacer click.

Comment: también me esta añadiendo a la lista o lo esta duplicando la idea es que solo muestre el ítem en la parte superior, me duplica el ítem en el listado

Comment: ya solucioné el tema de la duplicidad erra poner otro array, estaba usando el mismo por eso se duplicaba, una duda mas como hago para que el que ya se selecciono y este activo ya no se pueda volver a seleccionarlo

Comment: Ahí actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: una duda como le pasa un estado diablead, mas que diablead es cambiarle el estilo como bloqueado el fondo del color del botón del que ya hizo clic y fue añadido,

Comment: Agregué una actualización.

Comment: Hola una consulta, como puede añadir, o hacer el push respetando los elementos añadidos, lo que sucede es que si cierro es acción y vuelvo a realizar, se sobrescriben los datos mesecito que se queden los anteriores y que siga añadiendo sin eliminarlos,